# Mesh bend as it follow curve along path

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

With mesh (stairs) following the curve path. Few stairs are in align rest as it goes up the stairs bending. Rotation scale applied. Tilt is also 0. Whats going wrong. Any suggestion or help Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The _mean_ tilt is 0 but are all the individual control points tilts set to 0 ?

Comment: @Gorgious how to check individual point and fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Tilt* of the vertices are at 0° (*3D View > N* panel) so it's not the problem. You need to select the curve and choose *Twist Method > Z-Up*. That said the object is still not completely vertical. If it's too noticeable you need to switch to the *Instancing* method: Give the *Array* and *Curve* modifier to a vertex instead of your object, enable the *Instancing > Vertex* of this vertex, and parent your object to the vertex.

[image]

Comment: Thanks its just a single click.

Comment: yes I almost forgot this one  ;)

Comment: I tried above method with new mesh why its not follow with the curve. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183554/why-the-mesh-bend-as-it-follow-curve